# Access a variable in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How can I access the strings of 'X'

```
list = [['X','Y','Z'], ['X','Z','Y']]
```

For example I want to define a function to return `True` if `list[1]` of both list is equal to `'X'`

Comment: `all('X' in x[0] for x in your_list)`

Comment: that's an answer, write it and sign the question as answered:)

Comment: I could; but it is too trivial; OP did not try a bit.

Comment: `all('X' in x[0] for x in your_list)` is wrong, `"X" in "FOO X"` is True

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` to see if all ith elements in each sublist are the same:

```
def is_equal(l, i):
    first = l[0][i]
    return all(sub[i] == first for sub in l)
```

You might want to catch an IndexError in case `i` is outside  the bounds of and sublist:

```
def is_equal(l, i):
    try:
        first = l[0][i]
        return all(sub[i] == first for sub in l)
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

If you want to explicitly pass a value to check:

```
def is_equal(l, i, x):
    try:
        return all(sub[i] == x for sub in l)
    except IndexError:
        return False
```

Comment: @Eric, no worries, you may want to let a user know if `i` was outside the bounds of any sublist

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_list(list):
    for a in list:
        if a == "X"
            return True
    return False

def check_list_list(list):
    try:
        return check_list(list[1])
    except IndexError:
        return False
```